# Is there any way to disregard a SQL stored procedure's output parameters?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000, output-parameter

I have a stored procedure that performs some processing and returns a bunch of output parameters. I want to call the stored procedure just for the processing, and don't really care about the output parameters. Is there any way to call the stored procedure *without* having to declare variables for all the output parameters?

In case this isn't clear... I don't want my stored procedure call to have to look like this:

```
DECLARE @param1, @param2, @param3 float
DECLARE @param4, @param5 datetime
DECLARE @param6, @param7, @param8, @param9 int
etc.,etc.
EXEC MyStoredProcedure @param1 OUTPUT, @param2 OUTPUT, @param3 OUTPUT, @param4 OUTPUT.......
```

I want to be able to just say:

```
EXEC MyStoredProcedure
```

Is there any way to specify "I don't care about output parameters - ignore them"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the parameters in the SP have default values, they do not have to be passed in.

Comment: @froadie - If you set a default value to the parameter (`INPUT` or `OUTPUT`), you don't have to state it.

Comment: Yes, OUTPUT params can have default values, etc.  See my answer and give it a go...

Comment: got it, thanks... and I guess there's no way to override it just for one single stored procedure call?

Comment: @froadie - Not if it doesn't have defaults. Values are required for parameters.

Answer (score 3):

```
  CREATE PROCEDURE test (@id INT = 0 OUTPUT)
  AS
  BEGIN
    SELECT @id = @id + 1
    SELECT @id
  END
  GO;

  DECLARE @x INT
  SET @x = 9
  EXEC test @x OUTPUT
  SELECT @x
  EXEC test @x
  SELECT @x
  EXEC test
```